# How do I insert a link to download a PDF file in Angular?

Tags: node.js, angular, pdf, download

I am including an **About** page in an app I am writing.  This page should contain a link that downloads a PDF file when it is clicked.  Here is the **about.component.html** file:

```
<h1>About</h1>
<div class="panel">
    <p>
        Here is the first panel text.
    </p>
    <p>
        Here is the second panel text.
    </p>
</div>
<a ng-href="PDFFile.pdf" href="PDFFile.pdf">Download Information Sheet</a>
```

The link appears, but when I click on it, nothing appears.  **PDFFile.pdf** is in the same directory as **about.component.html**.  Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the pdf file to assets folder and change your link to "/assets/PDFFile.pdf".

Comment: Thank you.  I changed the line to:

<a ng-href="assets/PDFFile.pdf" href="assets/PDFFile.pdf">Download Information Sheet</a>

and it worked.  The "assets" folder is under the project's "src" subfolder.

Comment: @PyNerd also, since you're referencing local file, you don't need ng-href, href in <a> tag would be enough.